# Deleting const int* const ptrs when referencing another const int

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I have been trying to test pointers to understand it but got stuck on this.
Is there any way of properly deleting the `var2` in this case?

```
const int var1 = 3;
const int* const var2 = &var1;

//const3 = NULL;
//delete(const3);
```

Comment: Since `var2` is const, and what it points to was not allocated with `new`, there is nothing to delete.  If `var2` was not const, you could do `var2 = nullptr;`.

Comment: makes so much sense